# Display size product attribute values for variations in Woocommerce archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I have added a hooked function which displays the product attribute for variation assigned to a variable product on the Woocommerce archive pages:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'stock_variations_loop' );
function stock_variations_loop(){
    global $product;

    if ( $product->get_type() == 'variable' ) {
        foreach ($product->get_available_variations() as $key) {
            $attr_string = '';

            foreach ( $key['attributes'] as $attr_name => $attr_value) {
                $attr_string[] = $attr_value;
            }
            if ( $key['max_qty'] > 0 ) { 
                echo '<div class="sizeVariantCat">' . implode(', ', $attr_string).'</div>'; 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

It is working fine, but some of the data is messy… I only want to display 'Size' product attribute for variation values, not all the products that have a "size" attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to target the product attribute for variation "size" to get the corresponding values from the product variations set for the variable product, try the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'display_attribute_size_for_variations' );
function display_attribute_size_for_variations(){
    global $product;

    // HERE the taxonomy for the targeted product attribute
    $taxonomy = 'pa_size';

    if ( $product->get_type() == 'variable' ) {
        $output = array();
        foreach ($product->get_available_variations() as $values) {
            foreach ( $values['attributes'] as $attr_variation => $term_slug ) {
                // Targetting "Size" attribute only
                if( $attr_variation === 'attribute_' . $taxonomy ){
                    // Add the size attribute term name value to the array (avoiding repetitions)
                    $output[$term_slug] = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy )->name;
                }
            }
        }
        if ( sizeof($output) > 0 ) {
            echo '<div class="'.$taxonomy.'-variations-terms">' . implode( ', ', $output ).'</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). tested and works.